# Does passive trace start in Uplink, if I don't log in as an admin?

Tags: uplink

What if I use monitor bypass, password breaker, and after I got the password, I disconnect. No admin login, nothing in the logs, except the connection and the disconnection. Will they still passively trace me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there's little enough proof in the game that a passive trace is in progress until your server is raided, security response is alerted the second you start the password cracker.  That starts the active trace, but that part is the obvious part.

The log trail of connections from server to server is still there, and that's what the passive trace acts on.  Since you've created a security reaction, regardless of whether you use the password you obtained, it's safe to say a passive trace is in progress.

(I will attempt to test this at a later time since the game offers little proof, unless you wait for a passive trace to succeed and offer up your save game profile as a sacrifice, which is what I will try)

Comment: Alright, I tried to brake the password (only the password) of a bank. I connected directly, and used a Monitor Bypass. I got the pass. After that I waited for a week, and nothing. Guess that's working than. Thanks for the help!